# Does JxBrowser implement Web Workers API and other new HTML5 API's?

Tags: html, chromium, web-worker, service-worker, jxbrowser

I want to use service and web workers in a web application executed inside JxBrowser. It's said in JxBrowser's homepage that "supports the same web standards as Google Chrome", but haven't found anything inside its documentation about web workers, besides a reference to service/web/shared workers in a [constants class file](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc/com/teamdev/jxbrowser/chromium/ResourceType.html#SERVICE_WORKER) that doesn't clarify much about.

Anyone having used this features inside JxBrowser?
Does it implement Web Workers API?
What about other API's such as Cache API?

If anyone knows about this issues would be great, thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

[Web storage it's supported](https://www.teamdev.com/downloads/jxbrowser/javadoc/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "supports the same web standards as Google Chrome" phrase means that the web pages developed with the latest web standards will be displayed in JxBrowser exactly as in Google Chrome.

JxBrowser doesn't provide Java API for the all web standards. It provides Java API for Web Storage, but it doesn't implement Web Workers API. I mean it doesn't allow working with Web Workers API directly from Java code, but you can work with it from JavaScript on the loaded in JxBrowser web pages.